# using delegate functions for running app on different devices

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am writing a Windows Phone app. I have a **function called draw()** for which I want to have different implementations based on the device I am running the app on(tablet, Lumia 525 etc). I searched on the net and found that I could use **delegate functions** in C# to have different implementations. Now **what I can't find is** a way to determine inside my code, the **device** on which the app is running.(Perhaps I am not able to type the right query in to Google).

If I know the device on which the app is running, then I can use delegate functions to call the different implementations. Can anyone point me to a place which has a code snippet implementing the same.

Comment: Are you looking for this kind of information http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/iersoy/getting-device-information-in-windowsphone-7/

Comment: @JenishRabadiya...yeah sort of...but what I specifically needed is whether the device runs windows 8.1 or 8 which was not listed as one of the properties in the article....How can I get this?

Comment: @ColinE...Environment.OSVersion is not defined for Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the OS version via `Environment.OSVersion`

Comment: @ColinE....I am not getting 'OSVersion' under 'Environment' in Windows Phone 8.1 app...I am making the app for 8.1 but I want to change a few functionalities if app is run on Windows Phone 8